# Overlay transparent paths in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

```
from pylab import *
plot(randn(1000), randn(1000), alpha=0.1)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f756e65a450>]
savefig('test.png')
```

gives this:

[image]

Where the paths are combined, and then the transparency is applied after. I want something like this:

[image]

This was post-edited in inkscape to break up the paths and then overlay them. This isn't practical with the data set I'm using, because it's too large, and basically crashes my computer when I try to open it in inkscape. Is there any way to do this in matplotlib itself?

*Edit:* the actual data I'm using a single long vector of geophysical data, and I'm trying to plot a phase portrait with `plot(vec[:-1], vec[1:])`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a loop to create the plot:

```
for i in range(100):
    plot(randn(10), randn(10), alpha=0.5, c='b')
```

will give you something similar (the transparency is "added" for every iteration of the loop):

[image]

Depending on your data set, however, I don't know how practical this approach would be.

Comment: Also look into `LineCollection`

Comment: @tcaswell: could that b expanded into an answer?